# Multiple JqGrids Celedit causing jumping

Tags: jqgrid, cell, edit

I'm using 4 jqgrids (v3.6) on one page in celledit mode.
When user is editing a cell on a grid that is down at the viewport, the grid jumps to align the cell to bottom of screen.
How can I keep users view intact and avoid the auto scroll.
I'm not using dynamic loading of grids.

Thanks
Yatin.

Comment: Are you really sure that you use the retro version of jqGrid: version 3.6? jqGrid 3.6 was published about 7 years ago. It's really dead version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the upgrade worked..
Once upgraded, we did not see the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more detailed on the solution that worked? i.e. upgrade to which version, if you had to do anything specific, etc. This will help others searching for an answer to find what they need in a single place.